# connection in between view and database in mvc pattern?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am newbie to MVC  and class in PHP.I have made a  small application in that MVC pattern without any framework.I can access the template through controller and action in view.now my problem is that when the template is generated how the data inserted into it will be save in the database.So in short I want to know how the view file will save the data into database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the view posts back to the controller (ususally via a form), the controller should connect with the Model (database code/class) and save/update the data.

Answer (score 1):

This works in next 3 steps:

1. In view file you can put a form.
2. This form send data to a controller.
3. controller get data and call a function for insert in database, from model